# Mootools 1.25 in Joomla datepicker issue

Tags: joomla, mootools, datepicker

I have been noticed only today, that after i upgraded Mootools to 1.25, if an user browsing with Google Chrome (i guess also with Safari ) uses the Datepicker provided with ChronoForms (is the mootools datepicker library), the form is auto-submitted after the click on the date, without pressing any submit button.

This is not happening with Mootools 1.1, and it happens only with Chrome (and probably other WebKit browsers).

The problem is that the datepicker button is a `<Tab>` element, and its submit effect isnt halted like it was with Mootools 1.1

I have this problem in all of my sites, you can see an example here:

http://omnigrafitalia.eu/landinglifehotel/index2.php?option=com_chronocontact&chronoformname=testform

I find really strange that after half hour of searching on Google I didnt find anyone else with the same problem asking for help in some board/groups..

Best Regards

Alessio

Comment: The forums over at chronoengine.com would probably be a more accurate spot for such a question.  The developers of chronoforms check them daily and often will help you out by logging in and taking a look around your specific site to check the code.  They're a good group; with regards to this issue I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

if the submit/blur event is not being halted, search for `new Event(event).stop();` or similar and replace with `event.stop()` or preventDefault. `event` is the var name, can be `e` or whatever. 1.2 normalised events w/o the special constructor of 1.11